# from TXT to spatial data: lat/long formatting issue

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, spatial, data-conversion

I am trying to create a spatial dataset from a txt file imported in R and structured as follows:

```
CitiesTXTSel=

     COM   City_NAME     LONGI_DMS  LATI_DMS
     445   VILLEMOTIER   51916      462046
      98   CHAZEY-BONS   54054      454811
      57   BOZ           45434      462425
```

When I use the function below I get the following error message: 
"Error in .checkNumericCoerce2double(obj) : non-finite coordinates"

```
Cities= SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=CitiesTXTSel[,3:4], data=CitiesTXTSel[,1:2], proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=wgs84"))
```

I guess the pre-formatting of the cooridnates is not correct but I cannot figure out how to fix this. Please can you help? The imported coordinates are in Lat/long DMS.

Comment: I have no knowledge of R, but DMS in the headers likely stands for Degrees Minutes Seconds - you may need to convert them to decimal degrees?

Comment: Hi Jon, this can be a solution indeed. I have coordinates in another georeference system in the txt file. I am trying to use this one instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Reproducing your data frame
CitiesTXTSel <- data.frame(
  COM = c(445, 98, 7),
  City_NAME = c("VILLEMOTIER", "CHAZEY-BONS", "BOZ"),
  LONGI_DMS = c(51916, 54054, 45434),
  LATI_DMS = c(462046, 454811, 462425),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# a function to convert your input to decimal degrees
convert_DMS_dec <- function(DMS) {
  DMS_pad <- sprintf("%7s", DMS)
  deg <- substr(DMS_pad, 1, 3)
  deg <- gsub(" ", "", deg) # remove leading whitespace
  min <- substr(DMS_pad, 4, 5)
  sec <- substr(DMS_pad, 6, 7)
  DMS_split <- paste(deg, min, sec)
  dec_deg <- conv_unit(DMS_split, "deg_min_sec", "dec_deg")
  round(as.numeric(dec_deg), 4) # precision to about one arc-second
}

CitiesTXTSel$long <- convert_DMS_dec(CitiesTXTSel$LONGI_DMS)
CitiesTXTSel$lat <- convert_DMS_dec(CitiesTXTSel$LATI_DMS)

# re-order the data frame so columns three and four match your code
CitiesTXTSel <- CitiesTXTSel[, c(1:2, 5:6, 3:4)]

# Your code, indented a little for clarity
Cities= SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  coords=CitiesTXTSel[,3:4], 
  data=CitiesTXTSel[,1:2], 
  proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=wgs84")
)
```

and here's the resulting output of `Cities`:

```
        coordinates COM   City_NAME
 (5.3211, 46.3461) 445 VILLEMOTIER
 (5.6817, 45.8031)  98 CHAZEY-BONS
 (4.9094, 46.4069)   7         BOZ
```